# Absolute positioning within a table cell with flexible height

Tags: html, css, css-position, html-table

I have 2 divs inside a table cell and would like one to align to the top and another to the bottom of the cell.

I have created this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davew9999/3Mwz5/11/ which shows the HTML structure I have. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="top">This text is dynamic so can't set fixed height on this div. For example
                    this text could be very long while the others are quite short.</div>
                <div class="bottom">This should always be at the bottom of the table cell and also is dynamic
                    and can't be a fixed height.</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="top">Not much text.</div>
                <div class="bottom">This should always be at the bottom of the table cell and also is dynamic
                    and can't be a fixed height</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
td {
    padding:10px
}
.cell {
    position: relative;
}
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

All the solutions I've found involve setting a height on the wrapper div (the div with class "cell" in my example). This won't work for me however as the contents are dynamic.

I tried a solution whereby I calculated the height of the td element on load and set the div with class "cell" as the same height. This worked until I resized the browser window thus causing the table cell's height to change. I experimented handling the browser window resize event but this gets trigged a lot during a click and drag resize. It must work in IE8 and its slow JavaScript engine and with over 200 td elements to check this isn't a plausible solution.

A solution that gives me the desired output is splitting the contents of the div with class "top" and div with class "bottom" across 2 table rows, however I am wondering if there is a pure CSS solution to this or better CSS and JavaScript solution to what I've tried.

Comment: You already nailed it.. just add a height to the cell..

Comment: "This won't work for me however as the contents are dynamic." :)

Comment: Didn't see that one.. Well basically I think you need to use your calculation script again.. and then write this command afterwords if jQuery `$(window).resize(function() { // Do the same function again  });`

Comment: or as normal javascript: `window.onresize = function() {
    // function here
}`

Comment: I investigated this and found that the resize event gets called a lot during a drag to resize operation. The table is large (over 200 td elements) and it needs to run in IE8 which is very slow at executing JavaScript. I will update the question mentioning this. Also the questions asks if there is a pure CSS solution

Answer (score 1):

Can't test this as I'm stuck iN a lecture on my iPad but

Relative 
Bottom -1

Should fix an element to absolute bottom
Vise versa

As well As setting the height to the parent should work for forcing e cell to get the same height as the td ( 100% dose this ? )

Again can't test ATM,  until jfiddle fixes there ipad chrome/safari issues

Edit : won't twitter bootstrap do this al
 For you with there scaffolding classes ?

Edit 2 : scaffolding and responsive http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: When you say "Relative Bottom -1" what are you suggesting I should apply this CSS to?
I can't set a height on the td as the contents are dynamic.
I've had a look at the twitter bootstrap link but I'm failing to see how this will help?

Comment: Ill try to  repost a jfiddle in a little it.  Should help clear it up.  The response section of bootstrap creates tables and div that grow in shape with browser resizes

Comment: Thanks. I found this in the bootstrap documentation "Responsive utilities should not be used with tables, and as such are not supported". Looking through the documentation I don't think bootstrap would work for my situation but I must admit I've never used it before.

Comment: you had the chance to look into this?

Comment: Had a bash around with this and no,  you cant with the Bstrap components. spent a good 20 mins playing around.

Comment: Thanks for trying. It looks like what I'm trying to do perhaps isn't possible! I know there are limitations when it comes to styling inside tables and vertical alignment and perhaps this is one of them